# Stop band ripple vs stop band attenuation

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters

What is difference between stop band ripple and stop band attenuation in context of filters?

Comment: AFAIK stop band ripple is not a commonly used term. Can you provide a source please ?

Comment: The term "stopband ripple" is not uncommon. It is used on several mathworks pages (e.g., [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/practical-introduction-to-digital-filter-design.html)), and also on the [wikipedia page on Chebyshev filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter). If you google it, you get about 23.000 hits.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I generally agree with you, but first of all, this question doesn't look like a typical homework question (otherwise I wouldn't give more than a hint). It's a question about DSP jargon. Furthermore, even though you'll find quite a few instances of "stopband ripple" in a google search, it's not straightforward to find an answer to the actual question posed by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stopband attenuation is just how much the filter attenuates components of the input signal that lie in the filter's stopband. Stopband attenuation is actually a function of frequency, but very often the term is used to refer to the *minimum* stop band attenuation, which is usually achieved at the stop band edge(s).

The term *stopband ripple* is used for filters with a non-monotonic behavior in the stopband. These filters usually have several local maxima of the magnitude of their frequency response ("ripples") in the stopband. For filters with an equiripple behavior in the stopband, such as FIR filters designed according to the Chebyshev criterion (using the Parks-McClellan algorithm), or IIR filters with elliptic or a Chebyshev II characteristic, *stopband ripple* denotes the attenuation at the local maxima of the frequency response in the stopband. Due to the equiripple behavior, all these maxima have the same value.

In some filter design routines for filters with equiripple behavior in the stopband(s), the parameter *stopband ripple* is synonymous with *minimum stopband attenuation*. But note that this use of *stopband ripple* only makes sense for filters with an equiripple behavior in the stopband.