# High Resolution Spectral Analysis

Tags: matlab, dft, wavelet, filter-bank, resolution

Inspired by [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82743/fft-with-high-time-and-frequency-resolution) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-q9gwYZZ1o) I have been playing around with different methods in Matlab to do spectral analysis. In the past I have simpy used digital fourier transforms and played around with different window types, window lengths, step sizes and averaging.
Now I compared for different signals that approach with the "filter-bank"-method decribed in the video and with the "Wavelet synchrosqueezed transform".

With `y` being a time signal with sample rate `Fs` and `x` being a number of subsamples of `y`, one can calculate the DFT of this subset `x`. After the DFT calculation `x` is shifted for a certain sample-number called `step` and the DFT calculation is repeated. If this is done multiple times the time signal `y` can be transformed into multiple spectra. The frequency resolution of each spectra would be matched by the number of samples in `x`. The more samples, the higher the frequency resolution, but the lower the time resolution. The time resolution can be a bit improved by reducing the `step`-size but there is a limit.
I tried to compare three methods:

**1. Wavelet synchrosqueezed transform:** [Link](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wsst.html)

```
[sst,f] = wsst(y,Fs);
```

**2. DFT:**

```
hannEstimator = dsp.SpectrumEstimator('PowerUnits',"dBm",...
  'Window',"Hann",'FrequencyRange',"onesided",...
  'SpectralAverages',numAvgs,'SampleRate',Fs);

i=0;
FFT=[];
while (i*step+FrameSize)<=length(y)
    x=y((i*step+1):(i*step+FrameSize));
    Pse_hann = hannEstimator(x);
    FFT(:,i+1)=Pse_hann;
    i=i+1
end
```

**3. Filter-Bank method:** [Link](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.spectrumanalyzer-system-object.html)

```
filterBankEstimator = dsp.SpectrumEstimator('PowerUnits','dBm',
   'Method','Filter bank','FrequencyRange','onesided',
   'SpectralAverages',numAvgs,'SampleRate',Fs);`

i=0;
HSA=[];
while (i*step+FrameSize)<=length(y)
    x=y((i*step+1):(i*step+FrameSize));
    Pfb = filterBankEstimator(x);
    HSA(:,i+1)=Pfb;
    i=i+1
end
```

As can be seen the Wavelet synchrosqueezed transform doesn't need `step` and the subsamples `x`. Instead the resulting matrix `sst` has as many samples along the time-axis as the original time-signal `y`. For method 2 & 3 the variable `FrameSize` is relevant to tune time vs frequency resolution.

I tried multiple test-signals:

**Voice saying "Matlab"**

```
load mtlb
dt = 1/Fs;
t = 0:dt:numel(mtlb)*dt-dt;
y=mtlb;
```

[image: Matlab speech]
The "High Spectral Analysis (HSA) / Filter Bank"-method seems to have a bit of a higher resolution compared to FFT, but there is also a delay introduced.

**Chirp**

```
load quadchirp;
y=quadchirp';
t=tquad;
```

[image: Chirp]

The synchrosqueezed transform looks great, but the Filter-bank method looks odd.

**Multiple Tones**

```
FrameSize = 420;
Fs = 1;
NoiseVar = 1e-10;
Sineg = dsp.SineWave('SampleRate',Fs,...
    'SamplesPerFrame',FrameSize,...
    'Frequency',[0.16 0.2 0.205 0.25],...
    'Amplitude',[2e-5 1  0.05  0.5]);
y=[];
t=[];
for i = 1:1000
    y = [y; sum(Sineg(),2)+sqrt(NoiseVar)*randn(FrameSize,1)];
end
t=0:1:(length(y)-1);
```

[image: Multiple Tones]

The synchrosqueezed transform looks very odd. The Filter-bank method seems to work best besides the weird stuff happening at the beginning.

**2nd Chirp**

```
load quadchirp;
y=quadchirp';
t=tquad;
```

[image: 2nd Chirp]

The synchrosqueezed transform has a very high resolution in time and frequency. The Filter-bank method is doing worse than the FFT.

**Recording E-Motor**

[image: Recording E-Motor]
FFT looks the most clean.

**2nd Recording E-Motor**

[image: 2nd Recording E-Motor]
FFT looks the most clean. Because of the long recording time and the huge numbers of spectra generated with the synchrosqueezed transform I didn't plot it.

After these examples I am quite disappointed about the Filter-bank method and also a bit about the synchrosqueezed transform. I wonder if I have missed some parameters to tune the results? In all examples I used the same values for `step` and for `FrameSize`for DFT and Filter-bank. Also the value `numAvgs` was always the same for both. Further I played a bit around with the value `NumTapsPerBand` for the filter-bank method. But that didn't help much either.